# get xorg.conf serverLayout with c++

Tags: c++, linux, screen, xlib, xorg

I am currently working on a multi window application that spans over multiple screens. The software is written with xlib and runs on ubuntu 10.10, gnome desktop. 
To get the position of every window I'd like to access the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file, expecially the section SeverLayout. It looks somehow like this:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
     Identifier "aticonfig Layout"
     Screen     "screen0" 0 0
     Screen     "screen1" 1920 0
     Screen     "screen2" 3840 0
     Screen     "screen3" 5760 0
EndSection
```

I'd like to get the X values of each screen (0, 1920, ... ) Does xlib somehow provide access to this information?

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you consider under "X values of each screen" ?

Comment: with X value, I mean the absolute x coordinate of the screen. in this case 0, 1920, 3840 and 5760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information about layout of multiple monitors in X, especially when they're combined into a single logical screen, is available via the [libXrandr](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/Xrandr.3.xhtml) and [libXinerama](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man3/Xinerama.3.xhtml) API's.   Unfortunately, the multi-screen API's added to libXrandr in version 1.2 aren't covered in the man page, but require looking at the [extension spec](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/randrproto/randrproto.txt) and [Xrandr.h header file](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXrandr/tree/include/X11/extensions/Xrandr.h).

Answer (score 0):

You can use XWidthOfScreen and XHeightOfScreen functions.

Use XScreenCount (to get number of screens) and XScreenOfDisplay to get appropriate screen structure.

A better way is to get the root window of a screen and parse it's geometry using XParseGeometry function.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I looked into that one. but that still won't give me the screens coordinates. Of course in this example, I could just calculate screen0.x * screen0.width to get screen1.x, but I'd like to keep the flexibility to arrange the windows any way I want to.

Comment: @philip Updated answer. XParseGeometry should give screen coordinates.